# If statement not working as intended

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have a bit of code here and what I want to happen is that every time it is triggered the integer 'lives' goes down by one. Here is my code.

```
  if (match == NO)

    {
        self.wrongLetters = [self.wrongLetters stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:letterToCheck withString:@""];
        self.wrongLetters = [self.wrongLetters stringByAppendingString:letterToCheck];

        while (!lives == 0)
        {
            lives--;
            self.HangmanStatus.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Lives Left: %d", lives ];
        }
    }
```

But instead of going down by one it goes down all the way to 0.
Am I triggering it incorrectly?
Advice would be awesome, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
while (lives != 0) {
}
```

Another option would be:

```
while (lives > 0) {
}
```

This will guard against lives being negative somehow.

But if you just want lives to go down once, change the `while` to `if`.

```
if (lives > 0) {
}
```

The expression `!lives == 0` negates the value of `lives` then checks to see if that value is equal to 0. Not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`while(!(lives == 0))` should fix your issue.

Or, better yet, `while(lives != 0)`

Because of the order in which operations are applied, while(!lives == 0) is actually applying the ! operator to lives, which is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Lives is inside of a while loop with the condition "while lives is not equal to 0, decrement lives." Therefore, the statements in the condition are run until the condition is satisfied -- until lives is equal to zero.